# C++ Codeblocks Compilation Issue with multiple files OSX 10.11

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, codeblocks

I'm able to run single file programs but when it comes to multiple files, it will not run. Below is the simple code example and error. I have already tried changing to LLVM Clang from the default GNU GCC compiler but neither seem to work.

I've also already installed Command Line Tools and XCode as I was warned you would need this to have codeblocks working correctly.

This is the main.cpp, Sally.h and Sally.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sally.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    Sally s;
    return 0;
}

#ifndef SALLY_H
#define SALLY_H
class Sally
{
    public:
       Sally();
    protected:
    private:
};
#endif // SALLY_H

#include "Sally.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Sally::Sally()
{
    cout << "wuttup" << endl;
}
```

The error message I'm getting is this:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -I -c /Users/shackletom/Desktop/Test/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Sally::Sally()", referenced from:
      _main in main-9bf1fd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Edit, apologies, here's the full build log:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.11.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 253.9 -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2 -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/shackletom/Desktop/Test -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 179 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.11.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/yf/ky2mbh0x0b71x9gdz0g8sp940000gn/T/main-885784.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 7.0.2 based upon LLVM 3.7.0svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11.0 -o test /var/folders/yf/ky2mbh0x0b71x9gdz0g8sp940000gn/T/main-885784.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Sally::Sally()", referenced from:
      _main in main-885784.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

## Update:

Turns out that while creating the other classes I fixed this problem by making sure "Add paths to project" under File Policy was unticked.

Comment: `Sally.cpp` probably is not part of your project. I have not used codeblocks in years so I can't help with that.

Comment: When going through adding a new class it prompts you to put the file into the same project, I did do this. Thanks for trying to help though

Comment: The `g++ ...` command you have posted from the build log is
a compile command but the error is a linkage error, which arises
from the subsequent `g++ ...` linker command that you have not posted.
Post the complete build log, verbatim. It is most likely you
are not linking `Sally.o` but we can't tell without your linker command.

Comment: My bad, I'll add the full version as an answer so it's easier to read.

Comment: Verbose output isn't necessary but anyhow the log shows that you're
only compiling and linking `main.cpp`. There's no sign of `Sally.cpp`.
Hence the undefined symbol error for `Sally::Sally()`. Apparently you
haven't added this file to the project.

Comment: Cheers Mike, I had a look through and found where I was going wrong. Updated with the answer for anybody else having this issue. :)

Comment: (Aside: please format logs using the code tool. This will save you heaps of time, as you'll find that break tags do not need inserting).